# Why my customized CSS for a wordpress theme is not working from cpanel?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to update the CSS of a theme I am using. To test if it works, I am `display: none` to a `div`.
Firstly I tried customizing the main `style.css` file of that theme

```
.comment-avatar {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 92px;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

I set it to

```
.comment-avatar {
    display: none;
    width: 92px;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

It's not working. But it does work if I edit it from "Addtional CSS" or "Custom CSS" provided in wordpress. But both of these increases the load time of my website.

I am looking around for a way to customize the main CSS file of that theme.

**Edit**: I am updating the theme's `style.css` but browser I am seeing that the style is applied from 'style.min.css' file which is also on the root. Aren't my changes to 'style.css' not reflected intp `style.min.css` automatically?

[image: browser]

Comment: Clear cache and see if that helps.I suspect you still see styles with `display: table-cell;`?

Comment: is it a child theme? Is the style.css blank / only comments? Is the style.css being called via functions.php ?

Comment: @Morpheus I opened the link in incognito mode, still it's showing `display: table-cell;`

Comment: @TobiasM No it's not the child theme, it's the file `Style.css` present on the root of theme. I varified if that is the file which is getting load, and yes each CSS rule in this file macthes the CSS rules in browser

Comment: Can you see if your CSS is getting overruled? Perhaps, have you tried with display: none !important; ?

Comment: @TobiasM Yes I treid `!important`, but it's not getting overruled.

Comment: @TheCoder incognito window won't clear server cache ;)

Comment: @Morpheus Cleared the Cache, still not working.

Comment: If you simply can't clear cache ( your issue is related to it ) update your theme's style.css file from WordPress theme editor. This will clear all cache and should show updated stylesheet.

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan I am updating theme's `style.css` only.

Comment: Guys, please see the Edit.

Comment: style.css and style.min.css not the same files( min is minified version of style.css, but can contain any other css rules ). It's updated in some theme's automatically, but there isn't any function from WordPress core, which will do such minification

Answer (score 0):

To your CSS, try to give `!important` tag as shown below

```
.comment-avatar {
    display: none !important;
    width: 92px;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

and then clear the cache.

Comment: then add one more plugin, "Simple css". after installing, you will find this plugin under Appearance, write your CSS code then and update it..I think this will solve your problem

Comment: That would work in the same way as I have mentioned the working solutions in my question.

Comment: Have you used any cache plugin?

Comment: No. Please see the Edit.